# Where is proxy setting saved on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 server inside my company network. It requires a proxy in order to access network outside. I configured the proxy during installation. After that, I found my proxy setting was saved in /etc/apt/apt.conf. But it's not in environment variables. However, wget is also able to download a web page through proxy. Where does wget (and other programs) read my proxy setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual I suppose nobody cared to integrate all the communications settings for the programs used in Linux/Ubuntu, which is a pity.

In 11.10 you have system wide settings in several locations:

#### /etc/environment

```
...
http_proxy="user:pass@my.proxy:port
...
```

#### /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02/proxy

The command `apt` has its settings in this file:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http:/user:pass@my.proxy:port"
```

#### /etc/wgetrc

The command `wget` has its settings in this file following the same format as the `/etc/environment` file mentioned above.

```
http_proxy="user:pass@my.proxy:port
```

Provided 12.04 has the same file configuration as 11.10 regarding these three programs you can edit these files for the server.

I had a script file to change all these things in 11.10 back and forth between my work and home, but now I am not using that script until I know more details about how 12.04 works with these issues.

Answer (score 3):

`wget` uses `/etc/wgetrc` in which you'll find HTTP and HTTPS proxy lines to uncomment and edit with your proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the linux command lines can make use of the environment variables `http_proxy` and `ftp_proxy`. Just set these in your .bashrc file or setup a shell script to set these environment variables prior to running commands such as `apt` or `wget` etc.

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyserver:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://proxyserver:port/
```

Answer (score 0):

wget, and many other programs, get proxy information from the http_proxy environment variable. Try the command `echo $http_proxy` in a shell to make it is set.

Comment: wget maybe but not apt-get (on 12.04.1)